# When does OS check signals?

Tags: linux, signals

For simplicity,let's suppose it's on a single core architecture.

OS' main responsibility is to assign CPU time to different processes.

When does it check signals?

My bet is that it checks it when switching context(hang proc A and wait B) ,but I don't have any proof..

Comment: What do you mean with *"signals"* in this context ? Interrupts ?

Comment: stuff like what `kill PID` generates.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't poll for them if that's what you mean. When someone *asks* the kernel to send a signal, it interrupts the program to handle it.

Segfaults are triggered by hardware interrupts. The interrupt handler asks the kernel to pass the message along. Timeouts are similar.

It's all event-driven. Although some of the events quickly and simply leave messages around to be collected later for later - mouse movements etc. What happens next is very system-dependent but *it's not a signal anymore*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer, sadly, depends on the OS. On most, if not all, OS signals are event-driven entities. For example, in the case of a hardware interrupt, the hardware sends the signal to the interrupt handler, which then does its stuff, usually upon a context-switch (like you suggested).

It depends on the OS exactly, but in the case of a signal sent from a specific program, it usually happens when you context-switch a process to be executed. Signals are then checked. In the case of `kill`, the kill command is "tied" to the process, and the OS' interrupt handler takes care of it.

Operating systems have interrupt handlers that deal with that kind of thing. They periodically check, but it realy depends on the OS. In the specific case of `kill PID` (I use this example because you used it in an above comment), it will check the next time PID is scheduled for continued execution.

Short but unsatisfying answer: it depends on the signal and on the OS.

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Sources: I've programmed operating systems before, and I've taken multiple concurrency classes.

Comment: How's context-switch done in the first place? In the single core case, OS should not have any control over the CPU as soon as it transfers CPU to a process,right?

Comment: In a single-core case, the OS still controls context-switching, although in a different way. It most likely uses a round-robin queue to know when to switch processes (simple solution). Single-core does not mean single-process :)

Comment: I don't know of any assembly that can tranfer control back to OS after some time period, is there?(I bet OS MUST have used this kind of assembly,but we rarely know...)

Comment: Can't name one by name, since it's been a long while since I've worked on one, but I know they exist and are way more common than people think.

Comment: Also, most signals trigger a syscall, which will transfer control back ot the OS.

Comment: @spraff ,never know this instruction before...no ,it's not assembly...we need to talk about assembly when discussing CPU,not c..

Comment: If you're not writing an OS, don't be writing it in assembly. It's hardware-specific. You can look at the `sched_yield` implementation for a particular architecture, although it probably gets defined inside the SCI.

Comment: @Je Rog: The OS sets up the platform hardware to generate a regular interrupt, known as the timer tick interrupt.  This allows the OS to regain control of the CPU regularly, even if the user process doesn't execute a system call.

Comment: To add to caf's description, typical values for the timer tick are between 100 Hz and 1000 Hz.

Comment: Also, what caf has describes is known as preemptive multitasking. Some earlier systems (Windows 3.1, classic Mac OS) used cooperative multitasking, where processes had to cooperate to give control back to the OS scheduler, and uncooperative processes could hang the system.

Comment: @caf ,which assembly instruction does this kind of job?

Comment: @ninjalj ,you mean Mac OS still uses cooperative multitasking now??

Comment: @Je Rog: That entirely depends on the particular platform hardware, and how it's programmed.  For example, the classic IBM PC PIT (programmable interval timer) is accessed using the `OUT` instruction, to ports `0x40` through `0x43`.

Comment: @caf ,that make sense, I know windows has a `KeSetTimer` function for pretty much this kind of job...

Comment: @Je Rog: I said Mac OS, not Mac OS X. Different OSes.